# Legality of HIV Positive Organ Transplantation in Oregon State of the United States

Tags: united-states, medical, oregon

Is HIV Positive Organ Transplantation in Oregon legal or banned? What are the names of the laws or policies controlling HIV Positive Organ Transplantation in Oregon? Where can I find information on the legality of HIV Positive Organ Transplantation in Oregon State of the United States?

Answer (score 2):

I don't find any state law on the topic. There was a federal ban on transplanting such organs but that was changed in 2013 by the [HIV Organ Policy Equity Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV_Organ_Policy_Equity_Act). It allows HIV-positive donors to donate to HIV-positive recipients, which was banned under the Organ Transplant Amendments Act of 1988.